# try catch issue with dice rolling, and checkbox issue

Tags: c#, .net

hey everyone i'm having troubles with a project, a try catch block. I need it to do the following:

> First Check for first roll, if true skip hold checks and roll all dice
>
> If false, Try the following ( 'lock' newly held dice (somehow) AND roll unheld dice )
>
> If no dice are held, throw exception

i have attached my code. i'm so lost can someone help....

```
public partial class FrmBupkis1 : Form
{
    private PictureBox[] diceImages;
    private CheckBox[] holds;
    private Random rnd = new Random();


    public Frm1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        diceImages = new PictureBox[6];
        diceImages[0] = pbxDie0;
        diceImages[1] = pbxDie1;
        diceImages[2] = pbxDie2;
        diceImages[3] = pbxDie3;
        diceImages[4] = pbxDie4;
        diceImages[5] = pbxDie5;
    
        holds = new CheckBox[6];
        holds[0] = chbHold0;
        holds[1] = chbHold1;
        holds[2] = chbHold2;
        holds[3] = chbHold3;
        holds[4] = chbHold4;
        holds[5] = chbHold5;
    }
    
    private void rollBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    
        //First Check for first roll, if true skip hold checks and roll all dice
        //If false, Try the following ( 'lock' newly held dice (somehow) AND roll unheld dice )
        //If no dice are held, throw exception
    
    
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                //if die is not held, then assign random number to image box
                if (holds[i].Checked == false)
                    diceImages[i].Image = iglDice.Images[rnd.Next(6)];
    
                try
                {
                    Random = random.Next(0, 6);
                    diceImages[i].Image = dieImages[Random];
                    rollBtn = true;
                }
    
                catch (FormatException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message, "Error. Try Again.");
                }
    
            }
    
        }
    
    private void gameOverBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
    
            diceImages[i].Image = null;
            holds[i].Checked = false;
            holds[i].Enabled = true;
        }
    }
    
    
    private void quitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //btnQuit
        this.Close();
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you "rerolling" each die twice?

Answer (score 1):

There's many problems with this code:

```
Random = random.Next(0, 6);
diceImages[i].Image = dieImages[Random];
```

Assuming `dieImages` should really be `diceImages` (otherwise won't compile)
you are using a variable with the same name as a .NET class - confusing. Also this variable doesn't seem to be declared anywhere - just use the Random instance you have defined globally directly:

```
diceImages[i].Image = diceImages[rnd.Next(6)];
```

Also you were using a range from 0 to 6 - use the single parameter method `Next` to get a range from 0 to 5 (upper boundary is exclusive) as shown above, otherwise you will get an `IndexOutofRangeException` eventually when you access `diceImages`.

Answer (score 1):

I see where you are trying to catch an exception, but I don't see any place in your code where you are actually throwing an exception.  Throwing an exception looks like this:

```
throw new ApplicationException("No dice are held");
```

Or you could create your own exception and throw it instead.  The exception would be like this:

```
class NoDiceHeldException : ApplicationException
{
    // define constructors here
}
```

and then you could throw the exception like this:

```
throw new NoDiceHeldException();
```

Comment: so i posted what i have now... can you look at it and help me fill in the blanks?

Answer (score 1):

so i have this below for my try catch throw... still very confused on how it needs to work....ugh....

```
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                //if die is not held, then assign random number to image box
                try
                {
                    if (holds[i].Checked == false)
                        diceImages[i].Image = iglDice.Images[rnd.Next(6)];

                    if (holds[i].Checked == true)
                    {
                        //HERE IS WHER I NEED IT TO HOLD THE DICE IF THEY ARE CHECK AND ONLY ROLL THE REMAINING DICE. UGH I'M STILL LOST... 
                    }

                    throw new ApplicationException("No dice are held");

                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You must hold at least 1 scoring dice before rolling", "Format Error");
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am still confused about what you are trying to do, but trying to help anyway.  As you go through your loop from 0 to 5, you need to keep track of whether ANY of the items are held.  You want to throw the exception after you are finished with the loop (i.e. below it).  If you were to run the code you have now, for example, you would end up throwing the exception 6 times.

I think you will find that try/catch loop should be outside of your loop.  It should be like this:

```
try
{
    bool foundHeldDie = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        // your code, which sets foundHeldDie to true if appropriate
        if (holds[i].Checked == true)
        {
            foundHeldDie = true;
            holds[i].Enabled = false;
        }  
    }

    if (!foundHeldDie)
    {
        // throw the exception
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // handle the exception
}
```

To lock a dice (the place where you still have missing code), you could disable the checkbox (set the Enabled property to false), that way the user wouldn't be able to change it.

Comment: so i posted what I have, what it does now, is allow to roll all dice on first turn, then it will hold any checked dice, however it does NOT throw the exception message if no dice has been selected... I have posted my code with my updates.

Comment: ps heres a link to what the darn game should do.. no scoring or anything just the dice hold and roll etc. http://www.farklerules.com/play-online/

Comment: You removed the statement where you were throwing the exception.  Can you put it back, in the if clause AFTER the for loop.  Also, you need to set foundHeldDie=true.  Finally, I think Enabled=true will set the Form to enabled.  You need to set the checkbox to disabled: holds[i].Enabled=false.

Comment: i updated my code in my previous answer with what you told me, but with the way it sits, i am obviously doing something wrong, because the checkboxes won't work sice holds[i].Enables=false is causing a problem and i'm not sure if Enabled = true; is in the write spot either, also what goes into the catch section?

Comment: Inside the for loop (the one where you are setting the found variable and disabling the checkbox), you need an if statement where you check whether the checkbox is checked (held).  So: if (holds[i].Checked == true) { set found variable and disable checkbox }

Comment: but where does the holds[i].Enables=false go? where does the Enabled=true go?

Comment: I edited the code.  As you can see, I eliminated Enabled=true.  You still need to do the part before the for loop where you are using Random.

Comment: i am just so lost now... I updated my cold (as you can see) from what I think your getting at, and the error message still does NOT pop up...

Comment: I created a little program using your code (but fixed all typos) and the exception occurs if you start the program and then, before checking all buttons, you press the button.

Answer (score 1):

```
public partial class FrmBupkis1 : Form
{
    private PictureBox[] diceImages;
    private CheckBox[] holds;
    private Random rnd = new Random();


    public FrmBupkis1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        diceImages = new PictureBox[6];
        diceImages[0] = pbxDie0;
        diceImages[1] = pbxDie1;
        diceImages[2] = pbxDie2;
        diceImages[3] = pbxDie3;
        diceImages[4] = pbxDie4;
        diceImages[5] = pbxDie5;

        holds = new CheckBox[6];
        holds[0] = chbHold0;
        holds[1] = chbHold1;
        holds[2] = chbHold2;
        holds[3] = chbHold3;
        holds[4] = chbHold4;
        holds[5] = chbHold5;
    }

    private void rollBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //First Check for first roll, if true skip hold checks and roll all dice
        //If false, Try the following ( 'lock' newly held dice (somehow) AND roll unheld dice )
        //If no dice are held, throw exception

            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            //if die is not held, then assign random number to image box
            if (holds[i].Checked == false)
                diceImages[i].Image = iglDice.Images[rnd.Next(6)];
        }


        try
        {
            bool foundHeldDie = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
            {
                // your code, which sets foundHeldDie to true if appropriate
                if (holds[i].Checked == true)
                {
                    foundHeldDie = true;
                    holds[i].Enabled = false;
                }
            }

            if (!foundHeldDie)
            {
                // throw the exception
                throw new ApplicationException("No dice are held");

            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // handle the exception
            MessageBox.Show("You must hold at least one die before rolling.", "Error");

        }
        }

    private void gameOverBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {

            diceImages[i].Image = null;
            holds[i].Checked = false;
            holds[i].Enabled = true;
        }
    }


    private void quitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //btnQuit
        this.Close();

    }
}
```